# Javascript hash navigation & external js file

Tags: javascript, browser, hash, mootools

I have a question and may be you can help me.
I have a page (index.php):
...

```
<head>
<script src="site/js/mootools-core.js" /></script>      
<script src="site/js/mootools-more.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/js/router.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/js/app.js" /></script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

...

router.js project: https://github.com/xrado/Router/blob/master/Demo/index.html

app.js:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){

   var Core = { 
      loadScript:function(url, callback){
         var script = document.createElement("script")
         script.type = "text/javascript";

         if (script.readyState){  //IE
           script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete"){
              script.onreadystatechange = null;
              callback();
            }
          }
        } else {  //Others
          script.onload = function(){
            callback();
          }
        }
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
      }
    }

   var router = new Router({
      routes: {
         ''     : 'index',
         '#!index'  : 'index'
      },

      onReady: function(){
         Core.init();                     // Render body here ... working! 
      },

      onIndex: function() {
         Core.loadScript("index.js", function(){
           index.init();           // ReferenceError: index is not defined      
           console.log('Index loaded...'); 
         });
      }
   });
```

});

Here is my external index.js:

```
var index = {
   init : function(){   
      $('div_content').set('html', index.render()); 
   },
   render: function() {
      ...
   }
}
```

If I tried to load my page I get this error:

ReferenceError: index is not defined
index.init();

Can't find an error two weeks!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
   var Core = { 
      loadScript:function(url, callback){
         var script = document.createElement("script");
         script.type = "text/javascript";
          script.onload = function(){
            callback();
          }
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
      }
    }

    Core.loadScript("index.js", function(){
           index.init();     // ReferenceError: index is not defined      
           console.log('Index loaded...'); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>​
```

My assumption would be that as "window.addEvent("domready"...." is no native method, mooTools does some magic and changes the scope for loaded variables. So just try out document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

HTH

Gekkstah

Answer (score 0):

haha, i see you are using my and xrado's Router class. :) in any case, the problem you have is in your init and javascript loader.

first off, this:

```
var index = {
   init : function(){   
      $('div_content').set('html', index.render()); 
   },
   render: function() {
      ...
   }
}
```

when running init methods, `this` will be the host object so `this.render()`

second, lazy loading re-invented. see the mootools Assets.js - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Utilities/Assets.js#L24-48

there's an error in the mootools source which means IE9 will revert to `onreadystatechange`
callback despite of IE9 already supporting load event. still, it's fine, it won't ever fire before it's ready. keep in mind the scope of index when brought in later.

I tend to also use RequireJS, which allows me to lazy-load resources in time for the app to work, it's a nice way of delegating stuff and being able to package them

### blatant self advert

Since your index.js looks like a view, I would recommend you look at Epitome, which I wrote to be able to structure such apps in MooTools - http://dimitarchristoff.github.com/Epitome/ - it's a lightweight MVP implementation based upon Class and Events. Comes with the same [router class](https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/Epitome/blob/master/src/epitome-router.js), works with AMD or normal script loading, etc. And has a proper view / model / collection / templating structure.

For example, look at the todomvc implementation of that in a hash app here: http://dimitarchristoff.github.com/Epitome/#examples/todomvc-reference - see the repo with example code https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/Epitome-todo.